# Ошибка Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error при использовании GET запроса

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, axios

**React app**

В общем у меня очень странная проблема, писал код на Mac, и все прекрасно работало, залил на GH page свой "сайт" и там все тоже прекрасно работает. Но когда я скачал с репозитория свой проект, запустил VSCode, и все вроде бы тоже работает, вот только мой локальный файл json с данными, локальный сервер не видит. В консоле вот такая ошибка:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (1.chunk.js:890)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (1.chunk.js:385)
```

Вот мой запрос. (знаю что для локальногоjson файла достаточно импорта и этот способ не правильный, но меня интересует причина почему на windows не работает, а на MAC работает.. И на гит хабе все ОК)

```
componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('./phone.json').then(({data}) => {
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указать название домена дабы избежать циклической зависимости и в последствие ошибки.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('name/./phone.json').then(({data}) => {
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
  }
```